# SSIS Data Flow sending "wrong" data values to destination

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am loading many tables from MySQL (ODBC connection) to SQL Server (OLE DB connection).

I have a source column [updated_date] of type BIGINT that contains Unix time format such as 1613745401. I am pushing this column to my staging tables as NVARCHAR(100), to be translated later. For some reason, I get a **completely different value**, in this case 14975585452373553 (again, expected value is 1613745401)

The weird part is that **the ETL works fine for all tables besides one**

I've tried changing the destination column to BIGINT and same issue. I've also tried converting to varchar on the source, and it gave me a completely different value - 210456936497

Wondering if anyone has run into this before, because I'm completely stumped!

Update: The driver I'm using is MySQL ODBC Unicode 8.0.3 which I believe is the newest

Comment: Has only one column in target migrated incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Connector/ODBC driver? It's always been a bit flaky, [e.g.:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-errors.html) _If you are using Connector/ODBC to link to a table that has a BIGINT column, the results are displayed as #DELETED._ The MariaDB version of the driver also fixed a bigint-related [SQL_DESC_FIXED_PREC_SCALE bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-216) back in 2019.

Comment: @P.Salmon, yes only one column migrated incorrectly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have no idea! are you saying upgrading to the latest driver may fix things?

Comment: Yes, drivers seem an inconsequential thing because connectivity is connectivity, no? However, one former employer was stuck on a point release of the MySQL drivers because they had built their ETL packages based on a flawed data type interpretation (strings were erroneously presented as non-unicode in "our" build) and redo-ing it was going to be prohibitively expensive

Comment: I would check the advanced settings in the data flow task and find that column, the data type in flow may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue going from SQL to a flat file. SSMS returns the correct values, but output to flat file was converting '0' and '1' to 'True' or 'False' and data type in ssis kept defaulting to Boolean. Sometimes it would return the value '255' even though the column only had '1' or '0'. I had to alter the SQL table from BIT to INT and then go to Advanced Settings in the OLE DB data source to alter to 4 byte signed integer and also update the data type in the connection manager for the flat file to 4 byte signed integer.